# Is it possible to custom position UI elements from UiSettings in Google Maps Android API v2?

Tags: android, api, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Can you position UI elements like the Location Button or Compass Button available in Google Maps Android API v2, UiSettings? Right now, by default, they all appear in the same positions.

Comment: Using `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` they are covered by the actionbar. It would be nice to position them below the actionbar.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I am not sure I understand. How would I access the window from the map fragment/view?

Comment: I don't think is possible yet. It's always possible to make the buttons yourself and add them where ever you want. You'd have to use animateCamera(CameraUpdate) to make the buttons work.

Comment: I ended up using the Hierarchy Viewer to identify the view used to display the button and manipulated it. Very hacky, I know, but could not figure out a different way/

Comment: @oviroa Could you please show us your solution. thx